# Sumar filas de un tabla jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, struts2

tengo la siguiente duda, estoy haciendo un page con struts2, muestro una pequeña tabla con varias filas, busco que 2 filas se multipliquen y el resultado vaya a otra fila con jquery

```
     <s:form method="POST" role="form"  action="CrearLeyesRecepcionXLotes">    
  <input type="hidden" name="lp.nomb" id="lp.nomb" value="<s:property value="#session.user.id"/>">
   <table id="balances" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>N°</th>
                       <th>ID Planta</th>
                      <th>Usuario Creador</th>
                      <th>Fecha</th>
                     <th>Peso</th>
                          <th>Au Recuperado</th>
                         <th>Sulfuro</th>
                          <th>Resultado</th>
                 </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tfoot>
             <tr><th>N°</th>
                       <th>ID Planta</th>
                      <th>Usuario Creador</th>
                      <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Peso</th>
                             <th>Au Recuperado</th>
                         <th>Sulfuro</th>
                          <th>Resultado</th>
                  </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                  <tbody>
                <s:iterator value="listaleyrecp" var="lr" status="number">  
                    <tr>
                   <td><s:property value="#number.count"></s:property></td> 
                 <td style="display: none;"> <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="details[<s:property value="%{#number.index}"/>].id" value="<s:property value="#lr.id"></s:property>"></td>   
                  <td><s:property value="#lr.codess"></s:property></td> 
                 <td><s:property value="#lr.nomb"></s:property></td> 
                <td><s:property value="#lr.fecha"></s:property></td> 
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="details[<s:property value="%{#number.index}"/>].peso"  value="20" readonly="readonly" 
                                                        style='background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3); border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.2); cursor: default;' ></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="details[<s:property value="%{#number.index}"/>].recuperado" value="0.00" required></td>   
             <td><input type="text"   class="form-control"   name="details[<s:property value="%{#number.index}"/>].sulfuro" value="0.00" ></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="details[<s:property value="%{#number.index}"/>].resultado"  value="0.00"  required></td> 
                 </tr>
                     </s:iterator>
                        <tr>
                      <td colspan="6"></td>
                      <td colspan="2" class="text-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-round">Crear Leyes Recepcion<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></button>
                      </td>
                       
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                  </s:form>
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento realizar es que la columna "peso" se multiplique por la columna "Au Recuperado" obtiendo el resultado en la columna resultado por cada fila tal y como se muestra en la siguiente imagen :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano cualquier consejo o ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes los datos de la tabla? Lo puedes hacer a la hora de construir la tabla con [`rowCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback)

Answer (score 0):

Lo realice de la siguiente manera, creando el siguiente Query :

```
                  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    
     $(".classmulfil input").keyup(SumarFilas);

     function SumarFilas() {
         var multfi = 0;
         // buscar la row 
         $("tr.classmulfil").each(function () {
             // obtener los valores del row
             var $peso = $('.peso', this).val();
             var $recuperado = $('.recuperado', this).val();
             var $total = ($peso * 1) * ($recuperado * 1)
             $('.sumfiltTotal',this).text($total);
             multfi += $total;
         });
         $("#Totaltotal").text(multfi);
     }
```

Cualquier comentario para mejorar mi Query es bienvenido. Saludos!